# Any precompile macro to determine iPhone and iPad

Tags: ios, macros, precompile, ios-universal-app

I have logics like

```
DerivedClass extends iPhoneBaseClass

DerivedClass extends iPadBaseClass
```

Any precompiled macro can achieve this by just one single DerivedClass for universal iPhone & iPad project ?

Comment: Will you be creating 2, non-universal binaries from the one source?

Comment: NO.Just 1 universal binary. And I want reuse just 1 single DerivedClass for both iPhone and iPad. 2 different base class.

Comment: Then surely it would need to be a run time check. A precompile check would need to know the device before you build the app

Comment: So it can't happen with some macro or precompile flag ?

Comment: I don;t see how that would work, you can't precompile it and set it for iPhone if it's a universal binary as you could install that binary on iPad